# Is it possible to batch initialize regular variables in Java?

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, initialization

Is it possible to batch initialize some regular variables in Java in a loop? Here 'regular' means those variables are initialized alike.

E.g

```
Button btn1;
Button btn2;
Button btn3;
Button btn4;

btn1 = new Button(parentComposite, SWT.CHECK);
btn1.setText("Button1");
btn1.setSelection(true);
btn1.setEnabled(true);
btn1.setEnabled(true);
btn1.addSelectionListener(bottonAdapter);

bt2 = new Button(parentComposite, SWT.CHECK);
btn2.setText("Button2");
btn2.setSelection(true);
btn2.setEnabled(true);
btn2.setEnabled(true);
btn2.addSelectionListener(bottonAdapter);

btn3 = new Button(parentComposite, SWT.CHECK);
btn3.setText("Button3");
btn3.setSelection(true);
btn3.setEnabled(true);
btn3.setEnabled(true);
btn3.addSelectionListener(bottonAdapter);

btn4 = new Button(parentComposite, SWT.CHECK);
btn4.setText("Button4");
btn4.setSelection(true);
btn4.setEnabled(true);
btn4.setEnabled(true);
btn4.addSelectionListener(bottonAdapter);
```

As you see,the 4 buttons are initialized totally the same way. The only difference is that  the variable name starts with the same word `'btn'` and ends up with a increased number.

So can those buttons be initialized in a loop by reflection or dynamic proxy or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach would just be to create a method to do that:

```
private Button createButton(String text) {
    Button ret = new Button(parentComposite, SWT.CHECK);
    ret.setText(text);
    ret.setSelection(true);
    ret.setEnabled(true);
    ret.addSelectionListener(buttonAdapter);
}
```

Then:

```
Button btn1 = createButton("Button1");
Button btn2 = createButton("Button2");
Button btn3 = createButton("Button3");
Button btn4 = createButton("Button4");
```

You should also consider using a collection instead of four separate variables, if you want to be able to do further processing in a homogenous way. Then you *could* do it in a loop:

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    Button button = new Button(parentComposite, SWT.CHECK);
    button.setText("Button" + i);
    button.setSelection(true);
    button.setEnabled(true);
    button.addSelectionListener(buttonAdapter);
    buttons.add(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to initialize those buttons:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[4];

for(int i =0;i< buttons.length(); i++)
{
    buttons[i] = new Button(parentComposite, SWT.CHECK);
    buttons[i].setText("Button"+(i+1));
    buttons[i].setSelection(true);
    buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
    buttons[i].addSelectionListener(bottonAdapter)
}
```